# Converting JsValue to Vec<u8>

Tags: rust, arraybuffer, typed-arrays, wasm-bindgen, typedarray

I need to use `web_sys::Blob::array_buffer` which returns a `Promise` that resolves to an `ArrayBuffer`. `Promise` currently only resolves to `JsValue` in Rust. How do I convert that to `Vec<u8>`?

Answer (score 3):

First you must convert it to `Uint8Array` with [`Uint8Array::new`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0/js_sys/struct.Uint8Array.html#method.new) which takes a `&JsValue`.

Then you can use:

- **[`Uint8Array::to_vec`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0/js_sys/struct.Uint8Array.html#method.to_vec) to get a `Vec<u8>`**
- [`Uint8Array::copy_to`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0/js_sys/struct.Uint8Array.html#method.copy_to) to fill an existing `&mut [u8]` of the same size

```rust
let buffer: JsValue = /* ... */;
let array = Uint8Array::new(&buffer);
let bytes: Vec<u8> = array.to_vec();
```